# Converting application/json image to displayable image type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, file

I am using the hugging face API and the response sends back an image of type

> data:application/json;base64

How can I convert this data type into a more usable one such as a png or jpg file?

Example hugging face API response:

```
data:application/json;base64,eyJpZCI6IkxpbmFxcnVmL2FueXRoaW5...
```

Function which makes network call:

```
const { prompt } = req.body;
  try {
    const inputData = {
      inputs: prompt,
      options: {
        wait_for_model: true,
      },
    };
    const response = await axios({
      url: "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/Linaqruf/anything-v3.0",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.HUGGING_FACE_API_KEY}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
    });
    const mimeType = response.headers["content-type"];

    const result = response.data;

    const base64data = Buffer.from(result).toString("base64");
    const img = `data:${mimeType};base64,` + base64data;
    res.status(200).json({ img });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Server Error" });
  }
```

I need the image to be displayable by React Native's image component.

Comment: That API response's MIME type is `application/json`, not a PNG or JPEG. Are you sure that it contains an image?

Comment: Right that's a bit confusing to me. It is a text to image ML API though, so I would assume its an image.

Comment: It seems that you are using the inference API, so I'd think that the result would be data about inferences, not images. Maybe you're using the wrong API by accident?